# php postgresql pg_fetch_all

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm exeriencing a strange problem with `pg_fetch_all` (`postgresql`) : it never returns me more tan 2 columns

For exemple, this code :

```
    $dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbname user=user password=passwd");
    $query = "SELECT m.id, v.nom, v.id FROM machine m, version v WHERE m.id_version = v.id;";
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $query);
    $array = pg_fetch_all($result);
    print_r($array);
```

Only prints me `m.id`, `v.nom` !

If I paste the exactly same SQL request in pg_my_admin, each colomn is returned.

If I parse my result as

```
    $array = array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
      $array[] = $row;
    }
```

it works perfectly. Why ?

Comment: Consider using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database transactions, instead of making PostgreSQL a dependency for your application. PDO allows you to swap databases without your application needing to be modified.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Eden php toolkit, which use PDO for database stuff. http://www.eden-php.com/

Comment: PDO allows to use the same set of functions to access database but in no way it prevent developpers to use vendors proprietary SQL to write applications that just work with their database. So it is not true to say PDO allows you to switch database witht the same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you have two columns with the same name (in two different tables). You need to use an alias like this :

```
$query = "SELECT m.id AS mId, v.nom, v.id AS vId FROM machine m, version v WHERE m.id_version = v.id;";
```

You will then be able to retrieve the column `m.id` with the name `mId` and `v.id` with the name `vId`
You can find more info about alias in SQL [here](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-aliases.htm)

The reason it works with [pg_fetch_row()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-row.php) is because this one returns the result based on the index of the column on your query not as an associative array.

Comment: @Martin > Glad I could help. It is a good habit to use ALIAS in SQL query when you need to retrieve value, especially when you join tables. Don't forget to accept the answer!